# Connect Google Cloud Postgres From Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, shared-hosting

I just created a google cloud postgres with very basic authorization by whitelist the ip.

[Google Cloud Auhtorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gDu4.png)

I successfully connected to the google cloud postgres (35.240.xx.xx) from my home (139.193.xx.xx) using pgadmin and successfully created tables and inserted initial ddl.

[pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdb89.png)

When I want to use it in the shared hosting (119.81.xx.xx) that hosts laravel php application, I changed it in the .env file as below.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=35.240.xx.xx
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=[google cloud password here]
```

But it didn't connect when I run the website with laravel.log as below.

> [2018-07-12] ERROR: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused    Is the server running on host "35.240.xx.xx" and
>   accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? {"exception":"[object]
>   (PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to
>   server: Connection refused

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the shared hosting needs to also whitelist [google cloud external ip address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/). It's working now.